# parsing a numeric strings with backslash using regexp

Tags: regex, parsing

How can I get 3 separate regular expression from a string. I only need the numbers, I know if i use `\d` it will get me all the numbers '3/1/1' but i need 3 different regexp scenarios?

examples:

```
  slot/daughter_slot/port  
  3/1/1     regexp for slot only?
  3/1/10    regexp for daughter_slot only?
  3/1/2     regexp for port only?
```

thanks,

Comment: no - it can be up to 3 digits. ex 4/32/543

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regexp for slot only

`^/d+`

example http://regex101.com/r/eV2hI2/1

regexp for daughter_slot only?

```
\/(\d+)\/
```

The match group 1 contains the digits

Example http://regex101.com/r/eV2hI2/4

regexp for port only?

```
\d+$
```

example http://regex101.com/r/eV2hI2/2

Comment: Can i use this for xml ^^

Comment: When i try to test regexp to add it to my system I use www.regexr.com it always seem to work in xml, but when i add your solution to this website www.regexr.com doesn't highlight it.

Comment: @yescobar1 could you share the link for what you tried?

Comment: www.regexr.com but it doesn't display it to the url. Basically i added `3/1/1` ,`3/1/10`, `3/1/2` to the text and than i put your expression solution and does not highlighted it.

Comment: for some reason i cannot display it in my browser like you did. ok i see it works you change the flags. Your slot and port solution works. I couldn't get the daughter_slot to work.

Comment: @yescobar1 So you are using javascript. js does not support lookbehind. I have edited the answer see http://regexr.com/39t9s

Comment: oh ok i figure because we added it our xml file it was xml. Your solution for daughter slot kind of works but it grabs the both slashes can you do only the number?

Comment: @yescobar1 print the match group 1

Comment: i did not understand what you meant on your last comment @nu11p01n73R

Comment: @yescobar1 read this link for more details http://javascript.info/tutorial/groups

Comment: thanks I will atleastt now i know that its js regexp

Answer (score 0):

regexp for slot only

```
\d+/.+/.+
```

regexp for daughter_slot only

```
.+/\d+/.+
```

regexp for port only

```
.+/.+/\d+
```

Comment: However this feels very XY to me. What is it you're trying to accomplish with this regex and why? And along the same lines: what language and/or regex flavor are you using?

Comment: When i put it in the `www.regexr.com` it highlighted all of the string for all 3 scenarios you displayed. So this string comes in our system and we suppose to parse it and displayed it in 3 separate columns slot, daughter_slot and port from the string.

Comment: @yescobar1 sounds like you should be using capturing groups, but since I have no idea how your system is trying to split the regex into columns, nu11p01n73R's answer may be better.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't assume that the string starts with a digit and ends with a digit, and only contains digits or slashes, and you want to match only the appropriate digits.

NOTE: JavaScript does not support lookbehind (?<...), so this may not work in your environment. Also, forward slashes (/) may have to be escaped (\/).

slot only ([example](http://regex101.com/r/yN1jN7/1))

```
(?<!/|\d)\d+(?=/)
```

daughter slot only ([example](http://regex101.com/r/vR1bL2/1))

```
(?<=/(?=\d+/))\d+
```

port only ([example](http://regex101.com/r/zX8fW9/1))

```
(?<=/)\d+(?!/|\d)
```

Explanation for slot only

```
(?<!/|\d) - Assert that the previous character is neither / nor a digit
\d+       - Match a sequence of digits
(?=/)     - Assert that the next character is a /
```

Explanation for daughter slot only

```
\d+       - Match a sequence of digits
(?<=/())  - Assert that this sequence is preceded by a /...
   ?=\d+/ - ... which is followed by a sequence of digits followed by a /
```

Explanation for port only

```
(?<=/)    - Assert that the previous character is a /
\d+       - Match a sequence of digits
(?!/|\d)  - Assert that the following character is neither a digit nor a /
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    $re = "/(?<slot>\\d+)\\/(?<daughter_slot>\\d+)\\/(?<port>\\d+)/m";
    $str = " slot/daughter_slot/port \n 3/1/1 regexp for slot only?\n 3/1/10 regexp for daughter_slot only?\n 3/1/2 regexp for port only?";

    preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
    var_dump($matches);
```

[see live demo](http://regex101.com/r/eS8qH1/1)

Comment: slot, daughter_slot, port are just array key name. you may change these